# Proper shortcut to the Fill dialog box in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

What is the "proper" shortcut to bring up the Fill dialog box in Photoshop? In almost every tutorial on Youtube I can see `Shift + Delete` being used, which doesn't work for me. I'm on Windows and I use `Shift + Backspace`. `Shift + Del` is probably a MacOS version, but it would be quite unusual to have 2 different shortcuts for 2 operating systems. To make things more complicated, under Edit -> Fill I can see `Shift + F5` as the default. It doesn't really matter as long as `Shift + Backspace` does what it's supposed to do, but I don't want to memorize not standard shortcuts in case I ever work on a diffferent computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on a Windows 10 right now and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>
 works by default in Photoshop bringing up the Fill panel. If the default is not working you may need to reset your preferences:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/preferences.html

> To restore preferences quickly using a keyboard shortcut: Press and hold Alt+Control+Shift (Windows) or Option+Command+Shift (Mac OS) as you start Photoshop. You are prompted to delete the current settings. The new preferences files are created the next time you start Photoshop.